# How to find out LineSeparator cordinates of a PDF file using itext api?

Tags: java, itext

I am facing a problem: I have a PDF file which contains 5 pages of data. I want to extract the data from that file. I am able to find the coordinates of texts but I have not been able to find the coordinates of lines.

This is the pdf sample

Name  Age Role

---

Ranveer 22 Engineer

---

Actually there can be so many details before this line and I want the line coordinate so that I can stop my loop over there coordinates so that it will take all details before that line.

So my question is how to find the coordinates of any line in the pdf file.

Comment: If the line is drawn using path commands, iText parser package does not support parsing it out of the box. It can be easily extended too do so, though.

Comment: IF we create A PDF document using iText and use like line Separator and the document will get created with line . so is there anything by which i can get the axis of the line ??

Comment: A `LineSeparator` is drawn using path commands. iText's parser package (in its distributed form) does not inform `RenderListeners` about path commands. **But** it is fairly easy to *extend* the current parser functionality to make it inform its listeners about path commands.

Comment: I am sorry but actully i dont know that path commands.i created my own Listener by extending RenderListener class which is containing renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) for text. in this method i want to get that lineSeperator. Can you please help  me in code so that i can get that line separator. its really very urgent

Comment: I described the changes necessary for also parsing path commands in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14319929/1729265). Getting the line separator in `renderText` does not really make sense, though, as iText (when parsing that document) doesn't have the quaintest idea whether that line is meant to separate text sections, whether it is part of some vector graphics image, or whether it is some kind of decoration independent of the text around.